# node.js Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory-while using local module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a node.js local module whose structure is as shown below :

```
common
--logging
----index.js
----package.json
----config
------logConfig.json
```

In my index.js I have written below code :

```
let log4js = require('log4js');
log4js.configure("./config/logConfig.json");
const logger = log4js.getLogger();

module.exports = logger;
```

In the other node project, I have added dependency in package.json as follows :

```
"LoggingModule" : "file:../common/logging",
```

And using this module as follows :

```
const logger = require('LoggingModule');
```

After this line I'm getting below error

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '\config\logConfig.json'

It is trying to search logConfig.json in current directory path under config folder and  not in required local module which is added in node_modules folder.

Let me know the solution for this.

Comment: Is your folder structure provided in question correct?

Comment: Just try  log4js.configure("config/logConfig.json"); hope it will work

Comment: I have got solution for this. Giving direct path in 
            log4js.configure("./config/logConfig.json"); will search in current directory instead require that file and use that in log4js.configure()  and the code will work.